# ListBox only updates the first time its called? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `ListBox studentListBox` in `Form1` and it displays the members of `studentList` which is populated by `Form2`. There is a class `Student` which contains a few different properties regarding each student.

I also have a function `BindData()` in `Form1` which sets `studentListBox` data source to `studentList`. It also sets `studentListBox` display member to `Name` which is a property in a class `Student`.

`Form1`

```
public void BindData()
        {
            if (studentListHome != null)
            {
                studentListBox.DataSource = studentListHome;
                foreach(Student s in studentListHome)
                {
                    studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
                }

            }
        }
```

BindData is called on `Form1_Load` and it can also be called by clicking the refresh button.

`Form2` creates each student and adds it to `studentList` inside of `Form1` It does this when the submit button is clicked

`Form2`

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comparator(nameInput) &
               comparator(idInput) &
               comparator(bdayInput)){
                variable_assignment();
                var tempStudent = StudentCreation();
                if(tempStudent != null)
                {
                    studentListForm2.Add(tempStudent);
                }
                testList.Add(tim);
                testList.Add(john);
                testList.Add(tempStudent);

                foreach(Student s in testList)
                {
                    homeForm.StudentListHome.Add(s);
                }
                homeForm.BindData();
            }
        }
```

`comparator()` is a function that makes sure the user input fields aren't empty.
`variable_assignment()` assigns the user input to the related variables.
`StudentCreation()` is a function that instatiates the `Student`

So like I mentioned in the title, the `ListBox` only updates the first time its called, after that, it remains exactly the same. I know that the `Students` are being added to the `List<Student>` that `ListBox` is bound to because I was `Console.WriteLine`ing them and I could see the new `Student` being added to the `studentList` every time the submit button was clicked.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Why you loop this `studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";`? It is enough if you do it once.

Comment: see answer below but if you just wish to continue the way you are coding just do this:

if (studentListHome != null)
            {
                studentListBox.DataSource = null;
                studentListBox.DataSource = studentListHome;
                studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
                }

Answer (score 0):

A few small things

```
if (studentListHome != null)
        {
            studentListBox.DataSource = studentListHome;
            foreach(Student s in studentListHome)
            {
                studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
            }

        }
```

the foreach is redundant since you need to set only once for the list box and not each item in the list box.

```
    if (studentListHome != null)
    {
        studentListBox.DataSource = studentListHome;
        studentListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

Next to answer your question you must use a BindingList rather than any other type of collection and then for the comparison and sorting you can implement IComparable and INotifiyPropertyChanged on the Student class itself.

And then you do not to rebind again and just modify the BindingList instance to manipulate the list and the listbox would behave in sync with the list.